# Set all radio buttons to false, then set one to true in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I can't seem to get my head around how to efficiently set all the radio buttons in a redux state to false then set the original action creator to true.

Right now I struggle by trying to copy the state object using `Object.assign` whilst also providing a way to change the objects which hold true for `item.type === 'radio'` to `false`.

Some code I thought might be close to the true way.

```
const state = {
  'some_id_1': {
    type: 'radio',
    id: 'some_id_1',
    checked: true
  }, 
  'some_id_2': {
    type: 'radio',
    id: 'some_id_2',
    checked: false
  }, 
  'some_id_3': {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'some_id_3',
    checked: false
  }
};

const state = Object.assign({}, state, (item) => {
  if(item.type === 'radio') {
    console.log('reset='+item);
    item.checked = false;
  }
  return item;
});
return state;
```

But of course this doesn't work as it's not how `Object.assign` works.

Of course I could also loop over the object's keys, i.e. 'radio_box_1_id', ... and set anything with `item.type === 'radio'` to false, or even bring these changed values out to a separate state object and replace it using another argument of `Object.assign`. But these seem like extra processing time and not the perfect solution I'm looking for.

Thanks

Edit: My goal is to set the items of my state to a state of NOT checked, if they are a radio, but try not to change the others. I want to do this efficiently if it's possible. I can set the right radio afterwards to true.

Comment: How do you know the one to set to true? Is it in your action payload?
Also, maybe you could show a state example (or, better, a full [MCVE])

Comment: I can set the one that was clicked to true as it's passing the id through the action. It's not the part I'm struggling with right now. The problem I have right now is. 'How does one use spread operators whilst maintaining a condition check' or 'Is that even possible?'

Comment: Still, an [mcve] would really be helpful I think

Comment: If you could at least give an example of the shape of your `state` object and the action payload you're sending it would allow us to point out how to achieve what you're after.

Comment: How do these things matter though, that's the context but I want to just use a common operator/function to do something but in a little obscure way. But yes. I think adding a small state display would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't specify the `state` shape nor your `reducer` code, this is a common operation.

If i understand correctly, you have an array of items (objects) with a `type` and `id` for each.
If the `type` is a `radio` then you will have a `checked` property.

If this is correct, you can use the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and conditionally return a new object (using the [object spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)) while you check the `id` inside your action payload.

Here is a small example:

```js
const state = [{
  type: 'radio',
  id: 1,
  checked: true
}, {
  type: 'radio',
  id: 2,
  checked: false
}, {
  type: 'text',
  id: 88,
  value: 'hi there'
}, {
  type: 'radio',
  id: 43,
  checked: false
}];
const action = {
  id: 2
};
console.log('before the change', state);
const nextState = state.map((item) => {
  if (item.type === 'radio') {
    return {
      ...item,
      checked: item.id === action.id
    }
  }
  return item; // not a radio, go on.

});
console.log('after the change', nextState);
```

**Update**
As a followup to your update, now that we know the shape of your state, when dealing with objects instead of arrays, you can iterate over the keys with `Object.keys` and use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a new object according to your conditions:

```js
const state = {
  'some_id_1': {
    type: 'radio',
    id: 'some_id_1',
    checked: true
  },
  'some_id_2': {
    type: 'radio',
    id: 'some_id_2',
    checked: false
  },
  'some_id_3': {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'some_id_3',
    checked: false
  }
};

const action = {
  id: 'some_id_2'
};
console.log('before the change', state);
const nextState = Object.keys(state).reduce((result,currentKey) => {
  const currentItem = state[currentKey];
  if (currentItem.type === 'radio') {
    result[currentKey] = {
      ...currentItem,
      checked: currentItem.id === action.id
    }
  } else{
   result[currentKey] = currentItem // not a radio, go on.
  }
  return result; 

},{});
console.log('after the change', nextState);
```

**Edit**
As a followup to Ulysse BN's comment:

> I had to downvote: your modified answer doesn't fully clone the state.
>   if after your code I run state['some_id_3'].foo = 'bar', nextState
>   will be modified as well since they share the same object reference.

This is misleading, if you are not mutating an object then there is no need to re-create it. This is not a mutation.

This is a common practice in `redux`, you can learn more about it in [Updating an Item in an Array](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array)

Comment: This is right and exactly how I did it. But my state is actually an object with a key 'components': { 'id': {...} , ...}` where each `id` key looks towards a radiobox object with simple information like (the id again and I may remove this later, type and checked)

Comment: Using an object instead of an array would be very similar. You just have to iterate over keys. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bggqaxq1/)

Comment: I had to downvote: your modified answer doesn't fully clone the state. if after your code I run `state['some_id_3'].foo = 'bar'`, `nextState` will be modified as well since they **share the same object reference**.

Comment: Of course it shares the same reference, and it's OK since this object haven't been modified, this is a common pattern in `redux` by the way. you can learn more about it in [Updating an Item in an Array](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array)

Comment: I cannot update my vote anymore (unless the answer is updated). If you update it, ping me and I'll upvote

Comment: @UlysseBN yeah I've already updated it. this is an important thing to know so i attached your comment and my answer to it to the answer's edit section. :)